# Any tax disadvantage from paying out mortgage earlier in The Netherlands?

Tags: taxes, mortgage, netherlands

I am an expat in NL, and not from an EU country (not sure if that is important though).

I got a mortgage to buy a house, and now I can pay some money extra. I understand that the interest I pay is tax deductible. For example (and correct me if I am wrong):

If I earn X per year, then I pay taxes over (X - the amount of interest I paid).

So clear I will get less tax return, because an extra payment means less load and thus less interest.

For me, the diff in tax return should not be bigger than the gain from less monthly payment as a result of reduced mortgage.

Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2):

In most<sup>*1</sup>  scenario's making an extra payment for your mortgage will result in an overall net benefit.

For recent and qualifying mortgages and under typical circumstances the Back-Of-The-Envelope calculation is for every €1,00 that residential tax payers pay in interest for their mortgage, they will get a tax return of ± €0,40.

When for example you make  an extra payment and reduce your outstanding mortgage by €20.000,- and your interest rate is 5% that means that you will pay `€20.000,- * 5% = € 1.000,-` less interest to your bank.
Because of that you'll also get ± € 400,- less tax return.
You will still come out ahead by € 600,-  or € 50,- per month.

(And spending wise probably even more, because with less remaining debt your monthly mortgage repayments will be reduced too.)

But the actual effect will be dependant on several variables such when your mortgage started, how it is structured, your current age and your gross yearly income as dutch income tax is progressive.

A secondary tax consideration:
In the Netherlands you also pay a wealth-tax when the total amount of your savings exceeds a certain threshold. Using your (excess) savings to make additional mortgage payments will reduce the amount of taxable wealth.

---

1. At the moment I can think of only one exception and that is when the interest rates on savings accounts start to climb and will exceed the fixed interest rate on your mortgage.